# Mapbox Android custom navigation view (Navigation SDK)

Tags: android, sdk, navigation, mapbox

I would like to remove all views in the navigation view like the summaryBottomSheet and the instructionLayout and basically make my own version of NavigationView.

I can set the visibility to VIEW.GONE but that isn't really what I want.

```
// Hide unnecessary controls
findViewById<View>(R.id.summaryBottomSheet).visibility = View.GONE
findViewById<View>(R.id.instructionLayout).visibility = View.GONE
findViewById<View>(R.id.feedbackFab).visibility = View.GONE
findViewById<View>(R.id.soundFab).visibility = View.GONE
```

Is there a good practice way to do this? For example extending the `com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationView` class? I looked in there but I don't know if that is the right way to do it.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're looking to add a "custom" UI paired with our navigation logic.  It may be easier to not use the `NavigationView` at all - just using the "core" `MapboxNavigation` engine.

Please see [this example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/services/android/navigation/testapp/activity/navigationui/ComponentNavigationActivity.java), which showcases this usage of the SDK.

Comment: Unfortunately the link is dead